# Check with Chai if an object doesn't contain any additional properties

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, bdd, chai

I'm working on an API and should return based on permissions only a subset of the actual object's properties. I'm writing my tests in mocha and chai and would like to test for something like this (given `res` is the response object from the server and `res.body` contains the received JSON data):

```
res.body.should.not.contain.properties.except(['prop1', 'prop2.subprop'])
```

in which case `res.body.prop1` can be any kind of object, and `res.body.prop2` is only allowed to contain the property `subprop` - which again could be any kind of object.

Now, I could write custom functions to test this, but I thought someone else had already a similar problem and there is an extension for chai for it maybe or some other library I could use instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, I do not think Chai offers a way to build a query like this. However, a [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) is a perfect fit for testing if an object matches a certain format. Luckily, a [Chai JSON Schema Plugin](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-json-schema) exists. Using that, the result looks like this:

```
chai.use(require('chai-json-schema'));
var bodySchema = {
    title: 'response body',
    type: 'object',
    required: ['prop1', 'prop2'],
    additionalProperties: false,
    properties: {
        prop1: {},
        prop2: {
            type: 'object',
            required: ['subprop'],
            additionalProperties: false,
            properties: {
                subprop: {}
            }
        }
    }
};
res.body.should.be.jsonSchema(bodySchema);
```

A short explanation:

- The `required` property takes an array of required properties. If `prop1` or `prop2` are actually optional, remove them from this array (or leave it out alltogether).
- The `additionalProperties: false` ensures no properties other than the ones defined in the `properties` hash are allowed.
- `prop2` contains a subschema, which can contain the same fields as the root schema and specifies the format of the sub-property.

Granted, these schema's can grow a bit large, but so would your validation function. Of course you can make the schema a true JSON file to separate it from the rest of your code.